# retrieve implicitly assigned dispId values for all members in an interface

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, attributes, com

Given a c# assembly that has ComVisible=true, how would you go about retrieving a list of the implicitly-assigned dispIds within a type?  I've discovered we can use reflection or a disassembler to get an explicitly-defined dispIds, but what about the implicit ones?

The overall goal is to get the implicit dispIds of an older version of an assembly so we can explicitly define them in all future versions without breaking compatibility with existing consumers.

Comment: Since you know the member names, you can query interface the object for IDispatch and then call IDispatch::GetIDsOfNames https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oaidl/nf-oaidl-idispatch-getidsofnames for each member using its name.

Comment: @SimonMourier unfortunately, the ComVisible=true flag does not appear to automatically add the IDispatch interface to the exposed types.  If i use reflection on the type and run GetInterfaces() i only see the ones that were explicitly set on the type in the source code.

Comment: You can't use pure .NET reflection for this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some C# sample code that allows you to do that (it's much easier from C/C++ because IDispatch is very special in .NET):

```
// get the object type from progid (or use other means)
var type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("ClassLibrary.MyClass");
var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

// sadly, we can't cast to a redefined p/invoke IDispatch of ours because its a .NET COM object
// and IDispatch has a very special treatment
// so we use the vtable directly
var dispPtr = Marshal.GetIDispatchForObject(obj);
var vtablePtr = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(dispPtr);
var methodPtr = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(vtablePtr + 5 * IntPtr.Size); // GetIDsOfNames is 5 methods away from IUnknown first method)
var getIDsOfNames = Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer<GetIDsOfNames>(methodPtr);

// ask for the dispid of "MyMethod" member
var dispid = new int[1];
var hr = getIDsOfNames(dispPtr, Guid.Empty, new string[] { "MyMethod" }, 1, 0, dispid);
Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr); // throw if not found

...

public delegate int GetIDsOfNames(
    IntPtr pThis,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid riid,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string[] rgszNames,
    int cNames,
    int lcid,
    int[] rgDispId);
```